# jQwidgets - Grid View button-cell clicked but that doesnt trigger a row selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, jqxgrid

So i'm creating a jQwidgets grid view and i'm filling it with some data.

I have a cell which is made as a Button :

```
{ text: 'Action', datafield: 'Action', width: widthInStr, cellsrenderer: editButtonFunc }
```

Here is the editButtonFunc :

```
var editButtonFunc = function(){
            return '<input type="button" onClick="showEditInventoryScreenFunction()" class="gridButton" value="Edit/Audit Log"/>';
        };
```

I want when the button is clicked to trigger row selection event to call this function :

```
showEditInventoryScreenFunction = function(){

            $("#jqxgrid").on('rowselect', function (event) {

                var row = event.args.rowindex;
                var datarow = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);

                console.log(datarow);

                var itemId = datarow.Action;

                console.log(itemId);

                inventoryController.inventoryEditItems(selector, data1, data2, itemId);

            });
        };
```

So now when i click the button nothing happens after that if i select a row or click again the button, then the jqxgrid onclick function is activating.

I want to activate the jqxgrid onclick function when i click the button.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample with the jQWigets Grid which shows how to handle button clicks. You may look at [jQwidgets Grid Popup Editing](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/popupediting.htm?light)